# Речевая ошибка? Как её исправить?

Tags: синтаксис

На примере фразы-вопроса:

> Каким является этимологический корень слова?

И как обнаружить и не допускать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **какой этимологический корень слова (в слове, у слова).**

Сочетание ***каким является*** некорректно.

Глагол ***являться*** может **управлять  существительными:** являться ***кем/чем.*** Например, предложение "этот фильм является лучшим" неполное, в нем подразумевается "является лучшим фильмом".

О местоименном прилагательном ***какой***

Здесь местоименное прилагательное ***какой*** – это не вопрос о качестве/свойстве, а вопрос **о выборе** той части слова, которую мы будем считать корнем.

**Из словаря:**

**КАКОЙ** 1. Обозначает вопрос о качестве, свойстве чего-л. 2. Употр. для выражения вопроса о порядке выбора.. **который именно, который из имеющихся.**

**ЯВЛЯТЬСЯ**, нсв. 1. к Явиться. 2. кем-чем. Быть **кем-, чем-л.**, представлять собой кого-, что-л. Она являлась хозяйкой дома. Хирургическая операция является печальной необходимостью. Он является членом учёного совета.

**ЯВИТЬСЯ** 4. **чем**. Стать, оказаться. Его приезд явился большой неожиданностью.

Answer (score 1):

А и нетути никакой речевой ошибки. Допускайте на здоровье.

> Этимоло́гия (др.-греч. ἐτυμολογία от ἔτυμον — истина, основное
>   значение слова и λόγος — слово, учение, суждение) — раздел лингвистики
>   (сравнительно-исторического языкознания), изучающий происхождение слов
>   (устойчивых оборотов и реже морфем). А также — методика исследований,
>   используемых при выявлении истории происхождения слова (или морфемы) и
>   сам результат такого выявления. Также под этимологией может пониматься
>   любая гипотеза о происхождении того или иного конкретного слова или
>   морфемы (например, «предложить более убедительную этимологию»), само
>   происхождение слова (например, «у слова тетрадь греческая этимология»,
>   то есть версию происхождения — непосредственно этимон).

Обратите внимание на повторяющееся "или МОРФЕМУ".

А морфема ли корень? А вот и да:

> Ко́рень — морфема, несущая лексическое значение слова (или основную
>   часть этого значения).

Comment: Разве проблема в "этимологическом корне"? Мне вот это "каким является" в качестве вопроса не очень нравится — звучит как калька с английского (а может, с праславянского, не знаю). Думаю, автор вопроса об этом спрашивал. А может и нет — сейчас половина вопросов на форуме таких, что поди знай, о чём там спрашивается.